# The right tool to reverse the sorting order of thousands of elements in HTML file

Tags: shell-script, awk, python, sort, html

I have a HTML file containing thousands of `<div class='date'></div><ul>...</ul>` blocks of code like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="date">Wed May 23 2018</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Do laundry
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Get coins
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Wash the dishes
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class='date'>Thu May 24 2018</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Solve the world's hunger problem
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Don't tell anyone
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Get something to wear
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class='date'>Fri May 25 2018</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Modify the website according to GDPR
            </li>
            <li>
                Watch YouTube
            </li>
        </ul>

    </body>

</html>
```

Each `<div>` and the corresponding `<ul>` element are for a certain date. The blocks of `<div class='date'></div><ul>...</ul>` are sorted in ascending order, i.e. newer dates are at the **bottom** of the file. I intend to make them in descending order, so that the newer dates would be at the **top** of the file, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class='date'>Fri May 25 2018</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Modify the website according to GDPR
            </li>
            <li>
                Watch YouTube
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class='date'>Thu May 24 2018</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Solve the world's hunger problem
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Don't tell anyone
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Get something to wear
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="date">Wed May 23 2018</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Do laundry
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Get coins
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Wash the dishes
            </li>
        </ul>

    </body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure what is the right tool, is it shell script? Is it `awk`? Is it Python? Anything else which might be faster and more convenient?

Comment: 1) what is your sorting criteria? 2) post the expected result

Comment: If would help for reference if you could give your textual `<li`> elements some sort of word (`1`, `2`, `3`, ... would suffice) to allow us to reference them with you.

Comment: Do the nested block of `<ul> ... </ul>` elements belonging to some of the `<li>` elements need to be moved as part of the reversal?

Comment: Is this XHTML (valid XML)? If not, could it be?

Comment: If you know any programming languages (including Python), most of them should have an HTML parser... that'd be the right tool.

Comment: You probably want some sort of DOM parser to do this for you; `awk` is a regex tool and parsing HTML/XML with regular expressions is the path to madness and despair.

Comment: @roaima It's a HTM5 document.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I posted the expected results with a simple working example.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Is there any DOM parser which you would suggest?

Comment: A nit-pick: Your example doesn’t match your description.

Comment: @G-Man I couldn't find the wrong description. Please feel free to edit my post if anything is wrong.

Comment: You say that all the `ul`s are nested inside one big, all-encompassing `div` block, but then you *show* a small `div` block followed by a large `ul` block. (Also, since you asked, I would not have guessed from your description that you have ``ul`` nested within ``ul``.) I wouldn’t want to edit your post, since I don’t know for sure which is right. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … So anyway, (1) From reading the description, I would guess that a block begins with a `<div>` and ends with a `</div>` (and this can be handled, in a somewhat ugly way, as a simple pattern recognition scheme). (2) From glancing at the example, I would guess that a block begins with a `<div>` and ends with a `</ul>`. (3) From examining the example closely, I would guess that a block begins with a `<div>` and ends with a ***matching*** `</ul>` (so it can’t be done as a simple pattern recognition scheme; you would need to count `<ul>`s and `</ul>`s).

Comment: @G-Man Oh! Thanks, I'm going to fix it. I appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extended **`Python`** solution:

**`sort_html_by_date.py`** script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime

with open('input.html') as html_doc:    # replace with your actual html file name
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
    divs = {}
    for div in soup.find_all('div', 'date'):
        divs[datetime.strptime(div.string, '%a %B %d %Y')] = \
            str(div) + '\n' + div.find_next_sibling('ul').prettify()

    soup.body.clear()
    for el in sorted(divs, reverse=True):
        soup.body.append(divs[el])

    print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))
```

---

Usage:

```
python sort_html_by_date.py
```

The output:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="date">Fri May 25 2018</div>
<ul>
 <li>
  Modify the website according to GDPR
 </li>
 <li>
  Watch YouTube
 </li>
</ul>
  <div class="date">Thu May 24 2018</div>
<ul>
 <li>
  Solve the world's hunger problem
  <ul>
   <li>
    Don't tell anyone
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  Get something to wear
 </li>
</ul>
  <div class="date">Wed May 23 2018</div>
<ul>
 <li>
  Do laundry
  <ul>
   <li>
    Get coins
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  Wash the dishes
 </li>
</ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

Used modules:

*beautifulsoup* - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ 
datetime        - https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime

Comment: It worked great. I just had to replace the date-time format with this one: `'%a %b %d %Y'`. Thanks for your help.